# Geodjango - how to close holes in multipolygons?

Tags: python, gis, postgis, geodjango, geos

I'm using postgis and geodjango and have a lot of region geometry as multipolygon fields and it seems many of these have holes in them, is there any method I can use to close these holes and retain the outer boundary?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/gis/geos/) states

> Whereas indexing on a Polygon will return the ring (a LinearRing object) corresponding to the index:

so in principle if `P` is your polygon, you can extract just the exterior ring (index 0), thus ignoring all the inner rings (defining the "holes"), and use it to construct a new polygon:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Polygon
P_ext = Polygon(P[0])
```